# Cannot convert from method group to Int32

Tags: c#, methods, compiler-errors, int

I want my small math program to look really sleek, and by this I mean under the `Main` method I have the following methods:

```
Greet()
UserInput1()
UserInput2()
Result()
```

In `Greet()` I just say "HI", in `UserInput1()` I want to collect the first number, in `UserInput2()` I want to collect the second number, and in `Result()` I want to print the result of `UserInput1 + UserInput2`. I can collect the number in `UserInput 1 and 2` but I can’t seem to send them to `Result()` without assigning values to them under the `Main()` function.

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Greet();
            firstNumber();
            secondNumber();
            result(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void Greet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, pls insert two numbers");
        }

        public static int firstNumber()
        {
            int num01 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            return num01;
        }

        public static int secondNumber()
        {
            int num02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            return num02;
        }

        public static void result( int num01, int num02)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(num01 + num02);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change this:

```
result(firstNumber, secondNumber);
```

to this:

```
result(firstNumber(), secondNumber());
```

and remove the calls to the 2 methods in the two lines above.

To call a method without parameters, you need the parentheses without content.

Answer (score 2):

> Cannot convert from method group to int

This error message occurs when you attempt to take a method (without invocation) and pass it as a type. The `result` method is expecting two parameters of type `int`, but you're attempting to pass it the method, rather than the result of the method invocation.

You need to store the results in a variable, or invoke the methods with the `()`:

Like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Greet();
    var first = firstNumber();
    var second = secondNumber();
    result(first , second );
    Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

or this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Greet();
    result(firstNumber(), secondNumber());
    Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the method like the following, So that the method result will be called with output from the `firstNumber()` and `secondNumber()` as well :

```
result(firstNumber(),secondNumber());
```

Few more suggestions:

Make the method `Greet()` to a re-usable one by passing appropriate message and then display it. so that you can use the same for all display operations. the signature of the method will be:

```
public static void Greet(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

The method `Convert.ToInt32()` will convert the given input to an integer value only if the input is convertible. else it will throws `FormatException`. So i prefer you to use int.TryParse for this purpose. Which will help you to determine whether the conversion is success or not. so the Method signature for `firstNumber()` will be like the following:

```
public static int firstNumber()
{
  int num01=0;
  if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out num01))
  {
    Greet("Invalid input");
  }
  return num01;
}
```

Hope that you will change the `secondNumber()` as well

Comment: Thanks Flat Eric, David Pine, un-lucky. Really helpful indeed. :))